# Added a base struct breaks overloading

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I'm working on a compiler for a toy language and I created a struct to hold the result of the lexing step. Now I want to create a struct to hold the result from the parser so I thought I would create a base struct since they both hold warnings and error but one has tokens and one has statements. This is what my structs look like.

```
struct Result {
    std::vector<Warning> warnings;
    std::vector<Error> errors;

    void add(Warning warning) { warnings.push_back(warning); }
    void add(Error error) { errors.push_back(error); }
    
    bool hasWarnings() { return warnings.size() > 0; }
    bool hasErrors() { return errors.size() > 0; }
};

struct LexerResult : public Result {
    std::vector<Token> tokens;
    
    void add(Token token) { tokens.push_back(token); }
};
```

In the part of the code where I was adding errors it looked like this.

```
result.add(Error { loc, "Unknown token" });
```

But after the change to the structs I get this error.

```
moo_compiler/lexer/lexer.cpp:272:36 No viable conversion from 'Warning' to 'Token'
```

When I rely on the code autocomplete it wants this.

```
result.Result::add(Error { loc, "Unknown token" });
```

but I can't fathom why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you define a function in a derived class it completely hides any function in the base class with the same name in the derived class's namespace.

That means that the `add` member function in your `LexerResult` hides the `add` member functions from `Result`.

To bring the functions from the base class back into the namespace of the derived class you can use the `using` keyword:

```
struct LexerResult : public Result {
    std::vector<Token> tokens;

    using Result::add;    
    void add(Token token) { tokens.push_back(token); }
};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c6d80fdf224bbbd)